# Firebase Real-time Database iOS Delete Key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a working real-time database on my iOS App.  Right now trying to add functionality from the client to delete their user_id and history.  Based on documentation, would be the removeValue function.  However, when I run I receive a swift error.  Here is my code:

```
 self.roofRef.child(user_name as! String).childByAutoId().setValue(dict)
 let conditionRef_ex = self.roofRef.child(user_name as! String)
 conditionRef_ex.observe(.value) { (snap: DataSnapshot) in
 let _tester = snap.value.debugDescription

 // here is line of code to remove user, which is causing the error    
 self.roofRef.removeValue(completionBlock: user_name as! (Error?, DatabaseReference) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That i see: you have to fill completion block of removeValue method...
And you can also delete by specifying nil as the value for another write operation such as setValue or updateChildValues.